# Structuring a form to sort $_POST variables into arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Having a mental blank with this problem, so I apologize if the answer is a bit simple. I have a table in a form that a user can "add" extra lines to. I can get it to clone perfectly, but what I need it to do is capture each row as an array.

**Example Table:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[]" type="text" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="stuff" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="morestuff" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[]" type="text" value="2"></td>
<td><input name="stuff" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="morestuff" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
$_POST[rowNum] = array(
    1 => array(
        stuff => valueA, 
        morestuff => valueB), 
    2 => array(
        stuff => valueC, 
        morestuff => valueD)
    );
```

Using `[ ]` for each item will bring them out in seperate arrays, and I'm unsure how you'd join them together properly doing it that way, so if anyone could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[1][stuff]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="rowNum[1][morestuff]" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[2][stuff]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="rowNum[2][morestuff]" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Notice the `rowNum[x][]` around the the 2nd and 3rd inputs' names. The first input you have listed in your question isn't necessary.

Comment: Tried this earlier, and got the values of all rows of `stuff` and `morestuff` in the array for row 1..

Comment: Thanks Mister Dood - Does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to put `[]` after each of them.

```
<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[]" type="text" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="stuff[]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="morestuff[]" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

In the PHP, you link them together because all the inputs from the same row will have the same index. You can loop on all of them at once:

```
foreach ($_POST['rownum'] AS $i => $rownum) {
    $stuff = $_POST['stuff'][$i];
    $morestuff = $_POST['morestuff'][$i];
    ...
}
```

**Note**: This doesn't work for checkbox inputs. The browser only sends the checked boxes, so they would be out of sync with all the other inputs. But you don't have any checkboxes, so this won't be a problem here. The solution for checkboxes is to put something in the value of the input that links it to the corresponding row.

Another solution that works well with checkboxes is to put an ID into all the fields:

```
<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[1]" type="text" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="stuff[1]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="morestuff[1]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="checked[1]" type=checkbox></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="rowNum[2]" type="text" value="2"></td>
<td><input name="stuff[2]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="morestuff[2]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="checked[2]" type=checkbox></td>
</tr>
```

It still won't submit the unchecked boxes, but all the indexes will still be in sync. You can test `if (isset($_POST['checked'][$i]))` to tell whether the corresponding box was checked.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar - but the problem is that this is a very very simplified version of the bigger problem, which includes checkboxes..

Comment: I added a second solution that may be better for you.

Comment: Thanks Again @Barmar! This also works! Again - massive thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<td><input name="1[stuff]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="1[morestuff]" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="2[stuff]" type="text"></td>
<td><input name="2[morestuff]" type="text"></td>
```

Comment: I would recomend against this method because passing any other data via `$_POST` becomes very difficult. You can't just simply throw `$_POST['rowNum']` in a `foreach` loop.